# Какую технологию выбрать?

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, ruby

Вопрос довольно таки заезженный, даже холиварный. Но от это не становится менее актуальным. Я веб разработчик, начинающий, работал к клиентсайдом -- не мое, но JavaScript нравится, поэтому ковыряю node.js. Этот инструмент спорный и пока годится Just For Fun, но не о нем вопрос. Не могу определиться с бекендовой технологией написания серверов и сайтов. Java никогда не нравилась и PHP тоже. Хотя Java еще не выкинул из кандидатов. Есть еще Ruby и Python - как вы считаете, годные ли это технологии, пользуются ли спросом, какие подводные камни влекут за собой? И какие есть альтернативы?
Вот недавно Гугл Go презентовал - каков фактор успеха у этой технологии? В общем ваши мысли, опыт, то что не жалко поведать :) Спасибо!

Comment: лучше было бы конкретизировать по каким параметрам ты хочешь сравнения. Без этого это чистый холивар, и такие вопросы удаляют.

Comment: Кажись, кроме гугля гоу никто не пользует.

Comment: @mikillskegg , [Карьера][1] [на Go][2] сделана.


----------


NodeJS Just For Fun говорите? А как же [все они][3]? Тоже балуются? :-)

Это отличная бекэндовая технология, особенно для специфичных случаев. Тем более что вам JavaScript нравится.


  [1]: http://careers.hashcode.ru/
  [2]: http://blog.hashcode.ru/2012/07/go.html
  [3]: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

Comment: Минусну вопрос т.к. у вас, как мне кажется, жестокая каша в голове :)

Comment: Да пожалуйста :) Именно из-за каши с спрашиваю тут.

Comment: Так разработка серверов и вебсайтов - по моему конкретно на том уровне, на котором и должно быть.

Comment: Erlang! хорошого специалиста по нему днём с огнём не сыщешь, так что будете пользоваться спросом

Comment: @Spectre угу и для любого вздоха писать свой костыль по причине отсутствия готового решения ^_^

Comment: Ув. Spectre, так дайте ссылки на ответ перед закрытием, раз он заезженный. Спасибо.

Comment: @mantigatos, они первые и пока единственные. Как говорили греки, одна ласточка весны не несет.

Comment: @Spectre, а много тех, кому нужны специалисты по Erlang?

Comment: @Spectre, Erlang это хорошо. Я на него поглядываю тоже.

Comment: Elixir, тогда уж. О стандартную библиотеку эрланга (не считая единственной красивой вещи — OTP за вычетом SASL'а) можно, местами, с горя убиться, аки об стену. Правда у Elixir'а крупный минус — документация еле-еле выползает из зайчаточного состояния, и все это на фоне того, что язык растет и меняется.

Впрочем, если сравнить с экосистемой какого-нибудь нодожыэса — это не беда. Из трех мини-поделок, написанных на ней в пик вау-эффекта, сейчас без напильника не заработает ни одна. Все API сто раз поменялись.

Мнение остро субъективно, ясно дело, take it, как говорится, with a grain of salt.

Comment: @drdaeman Exlixir -- временное явление для Эрланг сообщества из-за многочисленных обращений рельсовиков в Эрланг. Также как и таджикский на улицах Москвы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вики:

> Not to be confused with Go (programming language), a language released in **2009** by Google.

Не сказал-бы что это недавно. Язык специфический, так и не стал популярным.

Лично меня интересует другой вопрос - с чего вы взяли что node.js это 'just for fun'? С вами готовы [поспорить](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node).

Ну да, я понимая, вы, скорее всего, прогнулись под общественным давлением, либо просто сделали "правильный" вывод.

Но нет, так нет, по сабжу - Go лучше не использовать и основная причина в том, что мало кто пишет на этом языке, если выбирать между Python и Ruby, то выбирайте то, что больше нравиться вам либо то, что вы уже знаете (больше нравиться либо лучше знает ваша команда, если она есть)

Comment: Я живу в маленьком городе и тут node.js меня не накормит. Хотя я и не отрицаю, что это перспективная штука, и у меня большие надежды на него на будущее.

Comment: @stonedmind переехать же можно, не?

Если хотите на покушать заработать, то выбирайте либо PHP, либо 1C

Вот я, например, живу в городе, где вообще практически не нужны программисты, по вашей логике я вообще должен был бросить программирование

Comment: Почему. Стоит учитывать много факторов. Меня PHP не интересует =)